# Difference between app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1" and app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1"

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I have read from the official guide the following:

To constrain one specific side based on the dimensions of another, you can pre append W," or H, to constrain the width or height respectively. For example, If one dimension is constrained by two targets (e.g. width is 0dp and centered on parent) you can indicate which side should be constrained, by adding the letter W (for constraining the width) or H (for constraining the height) in front of the ratio, separated by a comma

In conclusion if I use `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"` it means that the height will be fixed and the width will be set to be the same size as the height? For example if my element has more width than height, if I use `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"` that width now will become smaller to be the samesize as the height but if I use `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1"` now what will grow will be the height to be width and height the same size as the width now is fixed?